# NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'value' was called on null. : populating list of dropdownitems for dropdown button in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to create a DropdownButton with the names from local json file... I am using futurebuilder to do so.. I am getting the error

From my debugging trials I've understood that its because of a calling on null...

```
  body: Container(
     color: Colors.white,
     child: Padding(
       padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
       child: FutureBuilder(
         future: DefaultAssetBundle
         .of(context)
         .loadString('data_json/quran.json'),
         builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
           var myData = json.decode(snapshot.data.toString());

             if(snapshot.hasData){
               list_Drop = 
                  List<DropdownMenuItem<String>>.generate(myData.length, (int index){
                     print("=============="+myData[index]['name_simple']);
                    DropdownMenuItem(
                      value: myData[index]['name_simple'],
                      child : Text(myData[index]['name_simple']),
                    );
                  });
                return DropdownButton(
                  isExpanded: true, 
                  value: selected,
                  items: list_Drop,
                  onChanged: (value){
                    print("on Cchange");
                    selected = value;
                    return widget.storage.writeSelected(selected);
                  },
                );
                // return Text("Hellooooo not null");           
             }else{
                return Text("Hellooooo its null");   
             }
         }
       )
```

```
I/flutter (28709): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (28709): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building FutureBuilder<String>(state:
I/flutter (28709): _FutureBuilderState<String>#aa30d):
I/flutter (28709): The getter 'value' was called on null.
I/flutter (28709): Receiver: null
I/flutter (28709): Tried calling: value
I/flutter (28709):
I/flutter (28709): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter (28709): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core/runtime/libobject_patch.dart:50:5)
I/flutter (28709): #1      _DropdownButtonState._updateSelectedIndex (package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart:619:35)
I/flutter (28709): #2      _DropdownButtonState.initState (package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart:581:5)
I/flutter (28709): #3      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3830:58)
I/flutter (28709): #4      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3696:5)
I/flutter (28709): #5      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
I/flutter (28709): #6      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
I/flutter (28709): #7      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
I/flutter (28709): #8      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
I/flutter (28709): #9      StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3878:5)
I/flutter (28709): #10     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2742:15)
I/flutter (28709): #11     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4867:14)
I/flutter (28709): #12     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2742:15)
I/flutter (28709): #13     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4867:14)
I/flutter (28709): #14     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2742:15)
I/flutter (28709): #15     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
I/flutter (28709): #16     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
I/flutter (28709): #17     StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3781:5)
I/flutter (28709): #18     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2742:15)
I/flutter (28709): #19     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
I/flutter (28709): #20     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
I/flutter (28709): #21     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3990:5)
I/flutter (28709): #22     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2742:15)
I/flutter (28709): #23     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
I/flutter (28709): #24     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
I/flutter (28709): #25     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3990:5)
I/flutter (28709): #26     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2742:15)
I/flutter (28709): #27     RenderObjectElement.updateChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4585:32)
```

Please help me understand this error.

I am expecting the drop-down button to list all the names from the JSON file.

Comment: Can you show the structure of data_json/quran.json?

Comment: Thanks Gunter... Here it is :    
       [
        {
            "id":1,
            "chapter_number":1,
            "bismillah_pre":false,
            "revelation_order":5,
            "revelation_place":"makkah",
            "name_complex":"Al-Fātiĥah",
            "name_arabic":"الفاتحة",
            "name_simple":"Al-Fatihah",
            "verses_count":7,
            "pages":[
                1,
                1
            ],
            "translated_name":{
                "language_name":"english",
                "name":"The Opener"
            }
        } ]

Comment: Are you seeing your print statement when it tries to print the simple_name attribute?

Comment: Thanks  tomerpacific... Yes I am able to see all the simple_name from the json file... Soon after that I m gettign this error....

Comment: It seems like the ```selected``` variable is not initialized. I also don't see its initialization in the code snippet you provided. I would advise seeing what is the initial value of it and changing it accordingly. That should solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks tomerpacific... I found the issue... The issue is the List.generate is not properly generating the list with DropdownMenuItem ... It is generated with a list of NULLs ... Can you please advice me how to generate the List correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to return the DropdownMenuItem from within the generator of the List.generate constructor:

```
var myData = json.decode(snapshot.data.toString());
if(snapshot.hasData){
    return DropdownButton(
      isExpanded: true, 
      value: selected,
      items: List<DropdownMenuItem<String>>.generate(myData.length, (int index) {
        final nameSimple = myData[index]['name_simple'];
        return DropdownMenuItem(
          value: nameSimple,
          child : Text(nameSimple),
        );
      }),
      onChanged: (value){
        print("on Cchange");
        selected = value;
        return widget.storage.writeSelected(selected);
      },
    );
 }
```